# Find the velocity of a particle $z$ in respect to $x$ on a plane $xy + yz + xz = 0$ if it starts at $(2,-1,2)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose that a particle in $\mathbb{R^3}$ stays on the surface $xy + yz + xz = 0$. If the particle is at the point $(2, −1, 2)$ and starts moving along the surface parallel to the $xz$-plane, how fast is $z$ changing with respect to $x$?

I think that the plane where the particle is is the plane $-x -z + xz = 0$ (it's the plane where $y = -1$). Then, i isolated $z$ and derivated $z$ in respect to $x$, and got $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}$, and i thought that this should be the answer.

But i'm not sure, do i have to compute this derivative? What should be the answer?

I'm also confused because this questions appears along with anothers chain rule questions, and i don't see how and why i would use chain rule here.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, now just plug in $x=2$

Comment: from the wording, the particle has an initial velocity parallel to the plane $y=-1.$  It does not say it continues inn that plane. The full surface is a cone of revolution around the axis $x=y=z.$  As you indicate, the intersection with the plane is a hyperbola, and it does not hurt much if you pretend the particle remains in the hyperbola. However, more complicated 3-D paths are allowed as well